# how to use tr to replace multiple sets?

Tags: text-processing, sed, tr

I want to use `tr` to replace digits `0-5` with `A` and digits `6-9` with `B`.

I tried using `sed` to do this:

```
sed 's/[0-4]/</; s/[6-9]/>/'
```

It works only once though so for example if I write `123` it will only come with `A23` rather than `AAA`.

Comment: In the code you put 0-4, but in task description you ask 0-5. Which is it?

Answer (score 11):

With `sed`, you need to add `g` so that it will replace all occurrences on each line:

```
sed 's/[0-4]/A/g;s/[5-9]/B/g'
```

With `tr`, you can either chain two `tr`s:

```
tr '0-4' A | tr '6-9' B
```

or provide the character conversions explicitly:

```
tr 0123456789 AAAAABBBBB
```

or even:

```
tr 0-45-9 AAAAABBBBB
```

(but I find the latter less readable since the 1-1 mapping isn’t immediately visible).

The repeated `B`s can be abbreviated (`tr` repeats the last character as necessary), and the ranges can be merged:

```
tr 0123456789 AAAAAB
tr 0-9 AAAAAB
```

For more complex replacements, splitting the command can help make its purpose more obvious:

```
tr 0123456789 \
   AAAAABBBBB
```

or, taking advantage of the fact that quoted ranges match the expanded lengths in this scenario:

```
tr '0-4''5-9' \
   AAAAABBBBB
```

I’m assuming the range split is 0-4 and 5-9, to split evenly, as in the first command of your `sed` example. The ranges can be adjusted as necessary.

Comment: I suppose `tr '0-4''5-9' AAAAABBBBB` might be a little more readable....

Comment: @DavidZ, and more portable. `tr 0-9 AAAAAB` is not POSIX. You'd do `tr 0123456789 '[A*5][B*]'` or `tr 0123456789 AAAAABBBBB` POSIXly.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the substitution globally for all the characters using the `/g` quantifier at the end. Without it, the substitution ends at first matched character and will *not* proceed subsequently.

One other way using `sed` to transliterate characters (similar to `tr`) available both GNU and POSIX

```
sed 'y/123456789/AAAAABBBB/'
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
tr 0123456789  AAAAAABBBB
tr 0123456789 '[A*6][B*4]'
tr 0123456789 '[A*6][B*]'
sed 's/[012345]/A/g; s/[6789]/B/g'
sed 'y/0123456789/AAAAAABBBB/'
```

A few notes:

- `tr 012345 A` is not POSIX as the second set doesn't have the same size as the first.
- `tr 0-5 AAAAAA` is only guaranteed to work in the POSIX/C locale.
- same for `sed 's/[0-5]/A/g'` where `[0-5]` can match a lot more than 012345 in non-POSIX locales.

Note that as of 2020, the GNU implementation of `tr`, as opposed to the GNU implementation of `sed` is not multi-byte aware (though I believe there exist some patches that add some level of support), so the `tr` approaches can't be used on GNU system in locales that use charsets like GB18030 where the encoding of most characters contains the encoding of decimal digits.

For example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$LANG"
zh_CN.gb18030
$ locale charmap
GB18030
$ locale title
Chinese locale for Peoples Republic of China
$ tr --version
tr (GNU coreutils) 8.30
[...]
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
[...]

$ echo '£12' | tr 0123456789 '[A*6][B*4]'
丄凙AA
$ echo '£12' | sed 'y/0123456789/AAAAAABBBB/'
£AA
```

That's because `£` (the British Pound symbol) there is encoded as bytes 0x81 0x30 0x84 0x35 where 0x30 is also the encoding of `0` and 0x35 the encoding of `5`:

```
$ echo '£12' | LC_ALL=C od -vtx1 -tc
0000000  81  30  84  35  31  32  0a
        201   0 204   5   1   2  \n
0000007
$ echo '£12' | tr 0123456789 '[A*6][B*5]' | LC_ALL=C od -vtx1 -tc
0000000  81  41  84  41  41  41  0a
        201   A 204   A   A   A  \n
0000007
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ranges are 0-4 and 5-9:

```
tr 0-9 AAAAAB
```

or

```
sed y_0123456789_AAAAABBBBB_
```